# we can never any more wish to be separated than that we can ever imagine a regret that we were ever joined

Tags: meaning

"Every day we live together adds to the security of my confidence that **we can never any more wish to be separated than that we can ever imagine a regret that we were ever joined**."

It's from Mark Twain's love letter to his wife(https://lettersofnote.com/2013/12/17/always-yours/).
The bolded part is very confusing to me. How can I interpret this?

Comment: Likelihood of our wishing to be divorced/otherwise separated, on a scale 0 ... 100: 0. //  Likelihood that we will ever regret our marriage: also 0. You can see why he sold more books than me.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, but if he was still around and still writing like that he probably wouldn't be selling many books.